# How to load arabic string.xml when device language is English

Tags: android, eclipse, string, arabic

It's very easy to place different string.xml files for multiple languages like:

```
 English
   Values
     String.xml


Arabic   
   Values-ar
    String.xml
```

but it only works when device language is changed. My scenario is I have to load a user selected language in the application, different from the one selected in the device so how can I load different `String.xml` files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the application language using the following code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

`languageToLoad` is a `String` variable like `"en"` or `"ar"`.